# GCC/CLANG Auto-vectorization on two dimentional arrays working on int, not on char

Tags: c++, vectorization

Can anybody explain why this function is well vectorized on int, short, float but not on 8bit numeric types like char or unsigned char ? 
Code from https://godbolt.org/z/0UIMt7:

```
typedef int S; // Try with char
void test_add(S **  A, S ** B, S ** C,
             const int nrows, const int ncols)
{
  for (int r = 0; r < nrows; r++)
    for (int c = 0; c < ncols; c++)
      A[r][c] = B[r][c] + C[r][c];
}

int main(){}
```

You should be able to reproduce this with clang or gcc:

```
clang++ ./bug_report.cc -O3 -Rpass-analysis=loop-vectorize -Rpass=loop-vectorize -Rpass-missed=loop-vectorize
```

For info, clang++ give me this message with 8bit types:

```
remark: loop not vectorized: cannot identify array bounds
      [-Rpass-analysis=loop-vectorize]
    for (int c = 0; c < ncols; c++)
```

If I add `__restrict__` on the 3 pointer parameters this get vectorized but it's not possible in my application where A, B, C are opencv `cv::Mat_` objects, not `char**`.

Comment: "You should be able to reproduce this with clang or gcc:

clang ./bug_report.cc -O3 -Rpass-analysis=loop-vectorize -Rpass=loop-vectorize -Rpass-missed=loop-vectorize " - Not without a [mcve]. You failed to provide a complete/minimal program that we can test.

Comment: I updated the code. Now it compiles.

Comment: That code never calls `test_add`, so I'd expect any decent compiler with the optimizer enabled to just throw away the function and not even bother to *try* vectorizing it.

Comment: If you compile this code with the flags that I provided, clang with tell you if the loop is vectorizable, whether or not we call the function test_add.

Comment: I'm not an expert, but I think it has something to do with aliasing rules. Add a few `__restrict__`s and the loops will be vectorized.

Comment: If I add `__restrict__` on the 3 pointer parameters this get vectorized but it's not possible in my application where A, B, C are opencv cv::Mat_ objects, not char**.

Comment: `cv::Mat_` has a different data layout, so how is that related to your question?

Comment: I got the exactly same problem with cv::Mat_ (double loop much 10x slower with cv::Mat_<char> than with cv::Mat_<int>), we can actually access them using the [r][c] notation.

Comment: @MatthieuG Only because `cv::Mat_` mimics the API of a `char**` does not mean it works internally the same way. Did you try directly adding two `Mat_` objects instead of looping over them? If that does not work, ask a question specifically about your problem (and add the `opencv` tag).

Comment: @chtz Thanks for your feedback! I created a opencv specific question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55676850/cvmat-unsigned-char-3x-slower-than-cvmat-int